# Cache flushing - Magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, configuration, cache

I made a custom admin page and i am saving some configuration fields there and then am getting a notification from magento that i need to flush the cache. Is there any way to do that from the module itself? maybe put a hook where i save the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `\Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface` as dependency and assign it to `$_cacheManager` in your constructor or get it from de `$context` (if you have) and then after save changes clean the related cache that way:

```
$this->_cacheManager->clean(array([tag1,tag2..tagN]));
```

You could find a complete implementation in Catalog\Product\Model

I guess you could use the "get" method of the ObjectManager to get the cache instance too, but I'm not sure if is a good practice.

Comment: This is great! 10x
I'm just not sure about which tag i am supposed to use..

Comment: It depends on what your configuration chances will affect, so you can start with config i guess (i don't remember the actual name)

Comment: I know for a fact it's config...but i'm not sure how to find out the name, the clean function always returns true, so that's not a good indication.
I tried 'CONFIG', tried get all type names from \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface ...
and still didn't work.

Comment: I even tried calling \Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushAll and then there is a notification that i flushed the cache..but still on the cache management page the cache is invalidated.

Comment: Can you check on debug.log if perhaps another event invalidate the cache after your cleanup?

Comment: There are a few events that invalidate the cache..
I'm clearing the cache in the afterSave method by attaching a backend module in system.xml... why is the cache invalidated and how can i clear it without invalidating again?
cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://mage2.dev/admin/admin/system_config/edit/section/yotpo/store/1/key/........"invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []

Comment: Ok, just an idea, you can add one more event after (which it is invalidating the cache), move your cleanup code there, and in the event that you are using now just set a flag in the registry to use in the new event to ensure that you are clraning the cache only after your  module changes.

Answer (score 0):

go into magento root folder using command

> sudo php bin/magento cache:clean

run above command.

**I hope this will help you.**